# Get value of Username text box in <asp:Login> LayoutTemplate

Tags: asp.net, textbox, webforms

I have just started creating a new Web application using ASP.NET WebForms (VS 2012). In the project I have a Login.aspx page with a TextBox (created automatically by VS):

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Username" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Now I need to access the value of that text box, and I am using the following:

```
String username = Html.Encode(Username.Text);
```

I get an error, stating that Username does not exist. In Login.Designer.cs the TextBox is not declared.

On the designer, when I select the text box it is identified in the Properties dropdown as:

```
Unnamed1.LayoutTemplate.Username
```

This is my first project in VS2012; I have not had this issue in VS2008 or earlier. Is there anything different here?

Comment: I think you should remove and drag-drop the textbox again or declare it in the designer.cs

Comment: Try restarting VS, that normally works for me when the designer file fails to build correctly

Comment: Is Username TextBox placed in asp:Login control?

Comment: @AdnanQ I tried with drag and drop, it did not work. Nor declaring it. I tried to restart VS many times as freefaller suggested but nothing changes.

Comment: @YuriyRozhovetskiy yes it is placed under asp.Login

Comment: Use `UserName` property of Login control (if you didn't assign ID property of Login control - do this). Follow this link for detailed info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.layouttemplate.aspx

Comment: @YuriyRozhovetskiy that was the solution. It is different from ASP .Net. Please write an answer here so I can set it as accepted.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access children controls of templated control till template property not marked with `TemplateInstance(TemplateInstance.Single)` attribute. And this is how ASP.NET templated controls work.

In this particular case you can use `UserName` property of Login control. Behind the scene, Login control will search own LayoutTemplate  for instance of `IEditableTextControl` control with `UserName` ID.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
string username=Username.Text;
```

Comment: Tried it... not working. The problem is that Username is not declared.

Answer (score 0):

Make it this

```cs
String username = Server.Html.Encode(Username.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes a Build -> Rebuild will fix errors like this.

Answer (score 0):

First convert your asp:login control to a template using the designer.
This works for me where login has a <div runat="server"> added in template:

```
HtmlGenericControl ChooseDiv = Login1.FindControl("ChooseFireDepartment") as HtmlGenericControl;
ChooseDiv.Visible = false;
```

This works with a dropdown list added to the same template:

```
var ddlList = Login1.FindControl("myDdlList") as DropDownList;
...
ddlList.DataBind();
```